# WPF Textbox - Append only

Tags: c#, wpf

I need a textbox which can contain a maximum of 8 chars which can be achieved by setting

```
this.textBox1.MaxLength = 8;
```

However, sometimes my program will pre-enter a few characters (i.e. 6). When presented to the user, I want him to be able to append the missing 2, but not be able to delete the pre-entered 6 characters.

I do not want to have something like

```
if(!textBox1.Text.Equals(strPreEntered)) throw new Exception(); // Or show a messagebox, or ..
```

Ideally I would like the Textbox to not accept any backspaces in case `textBox1.Length == strPreEntered.Length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is a flag indicating whether the TextBox has had pre-entered characters sent to it or not. Set it to true whenever you send the pre-entered characters to the TextBox.

Then in the TextBox's OnKeyPress event, ignore the keypress if the KeyCode is a backspace if the flag is set.

```
public class FormTest : Form
{
    public FormTest() : base()
    {
        LimitedTextBox tb = new LimitedTextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
        tb.Text = "123456";
        tb.MaxLength = 8;
        tb.HasPreenteredText = true;
    }
}

public class LimitedTextBox : TextBox
{
    private int preenteredTextLength = -1;

    private bool hasPreenteredText = false;
    public bool HasPreenteredText
    {
        get { return hasPreenteredText; }
        set
        {
            if (value == true)
            { preenteredTextLength = this.TextLength; }
            else
            { preenteredTextLength = -1; }
            hasPreenteredText = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.TextLength <= preenteredTextLength && e.KeyChar == '\b')
        { e.Handled = true; } // Causes the KeyPress to be skipped as it was already 'handled'

        if (this.SelectionStart < preenteredTextLength) // Prevent user from overwriting/deleting selected text beyond the minimum text length
        { e.Handled = true; }

        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

The above code's a little sloppy but you would of course want to clean it up. Maybe have a SetPreenteredText() method that handles setting the boolean value within the LimitedTextBox control and make the boolean private, you don't want to trouble the caller with that sort of thing. The code works as expected though and accomplishes what you seem to want.

Comment: Thanks. Yet the user would be able to enter a 7, highlight the characters 345 with his mouse, press backspace and thus modify the pre-entered text. Still the `OnKeyPress` seems to be the way to go.

Comment: I updated the code to show how you can prevent that as well, using the SelectionStart property to find where the beginning of the user's selection is.